# buscar linha específica do banco para preencher tabela

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Estou trabalhando em um sistema para técnico de instalação de internet e linha, e  preciso preencher uma tabela com um número X de instalação por tipo.

Até aí tudo bem, estou fazendo um `count` do tipo e agrupando para saber quantas instalações de cada tipo o técnico fez:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse é o resultado que meu banco gera, mas preciso pegar o resultado de uma linha específica da coluna `qtd` para jogar na minha tabela.

```js
function relatorioOs() {
  var Dados = $("#list_os").serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    crossDomain: true,
    url: bd+'/relatorio_data.php',
    dataType: "text",
    async: false,
    data:Dados,
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
      app.dialog.preloader('Buscando os');
    },
    success: function (result) {
      var data = JSON.parse(result);
      console.log(data);
      var htmlrelatorio1 = "";
      var htmlrelatorio2 = "";
      var htmlrelatorio3 = "";
      var htmlrelatorioT = "";
      $.each(data, function (i, item) {
       htmlrelatorio1 = 
       ' <tr>'+
       '<td class="numeric-cell">'+item.qtd+'</td>'+
       '<td class="numeric-cell">'+item.qtd+'</td>'+
       '<td class="numeric-cell">'+item.qtd+'</td>'+
       '<td class="numeric-cell">'+item.qtd+'</td>'+
       '<td class="numeric-cell">'+item.qtd+'</td>'+
       '<td class="numeric-cell">'+item.qtd+'</td>'+
       '</tr>';

       htmlrelatorioT = 
       ' <tr>'+
       '<td class="numeric-cell">'+item.total_os+'</td>'+
       '<td class="numeric-cell">'+item.total_pontos+'</td>'+
       '</tr>';

       $("#rel-os1").append(htmlrelatorio1);
       $("#rel-osT").append(htmlrelatorioT); 
     });
    },
    error: function () {
      app.dialog.preloader('Erro ao buscar os');
    },
    complete: function () {
      app.dialog.close();
    }
  });
};
```

Esse é o código PHP com as conexões com o banco:

```php
<?php

include_once("conectar.php");

$dataInicio = $_POST['data-inicio'];
$dataFim = $_POST['data-fim'];

if (!$conexao) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conexao->conexao_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT count(nome)AS total_os , SUM(pontuacao) AS total_pontos,tipo,count(tipo) as qtd  FROM dados_os where dados_os.data between '$dataInicio' and  '$dataFim' 
group by tipo" ;

if (mysqli_query($conexao, $sql)) {
    $result = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);

    if ($result) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
            foreach ($row as $key => $col) {
                $array_linha[$key] = utf8_encode($col);
            }
            $array_resultado[] = $array_linha;
        }
        echo utf8_encode(json_encode($array_resultado));
    }
    mysqli_close($conexao);
} else {

    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conexao->conexao_error;
}

?>
```

Comment: a linha especifica devera ser seleciona de qual maneira, nome? codigo?

Answer (score 0):

A tua explicação esta um pouco confusa.
Mias eu no teu lugar faria como na imagem. 
Com 2 ou mais inner join acho que da para resolver o teu caso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]